# Не работает скрипт для jquery Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Есть не большой скрипт для плагина jquery waypoints, код:

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.animated = function(inEffect, outEffect) {
                $(this).css("opacity", "0").addClass("animated").waypoint(function(dir) {
                        if (dir === "down") {
                                $(this).removeClass(outEffect).addClass(inEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        } else {
                                $(this).removeClass(inEffect).addClass(outEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        };
                }, {
                        offset: "80%"
                }).waypoint(function(dir) {
                        if (dir === "down") {
                                $(this).removeClass(inEffect).addClass(outEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        } else {
                                $(this).removeClass(outEffect).addClass(inEffect).css("opacity", "1");
                        };
                }, {
                        offset: -$(window).height()
                });
        };
})(jQuery);
```

После его подключения консоль выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).addClass(...).waypoint(...).waypoint is not a function

Сам по себе waypoints работает. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение данного вопроса:

```
(function($) { 
 $.fn.animated = function(inEffect, outEffect) { 
  var jQueryObject = $(this); 

  jQueryObject.css("opacity", "0").addClass("animated"); 


  jQueryObject.waypoint(function(dir) { 
   if (dir === "down") { 
    jQueryObject.removeClass(outEffect).addClass(inEffect).css("opacity", "1"); 
   } else { 
    jQueryObject.removeClass(inEffect).addClass(outEffect).css("opacity", "1"); 
   }; 
  }, { 
   offset: "80%" 
  }); 

  jQueryObject.waypoint(function(dir) { 
   if (dir === "down") { 
    jQueryObject.removeClass(inEffect).addClass(outEffect).css("opacity", "1"); 
   } else { 
    jQueryObject.removeClass(outEffect).addClass(inEffect).css("opacity", "1"); 
   }; 
  }, { 
   offset: -$(window).height() 
  }); 
 }; 
})(jQuery);﻿
```